# Cannot receive cloud function notification using Send to Topic Option

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Flutter and Dart to trigger cloud function push notification however, I cannot seem to receive any notification on my device. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(); 
exports.myFunction = functions.database.instance("fm-90011")
    .ref("orders/{userId}/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {  
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      console.log("Inside push notification");
      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("orders",{notification:{title:"New Order",body:'Tap to view',clickAction:'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'}});
    });
```

Heres how the orders structure looks like in firebase realtime database.
[image]

In the cloud function log, I get the log messages as seen:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Can you give an example? My understanding is that when a user submits an order, this notification should be triggered. I have already checked and ensured that when I submit an order, it gets saved to the DB.

Comment: I am newbie so  apologies for asking silly questions. From your explanation, it seems like what I want to do is related to database. I want to trigger a notification to particular UrserID when any other user stores data to ther orders table in DB. How can I do that using push notification? Is there another solution beside FCM?

Comment: How do I generate a token for a particular user? Also, I am confused when you say "device" token. Does that mean that if I login as an admin using a different phone, I won't be able to receive notifications?

Comment: But can't the fcm uniquely identify the user though UID instead of token? If UID was used, then there was no need at all to store multiple tokens. This is really going to be a problem because if  my client decides to use a different phone to login as an admin and I don't have that phone's token stored, then they won't be able to get notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the publish/subscribe model, FCM topic messaging allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic. You compose topic messages as needed, and FCM handles routing and delivering the message reliably to the right devices.

For you to send a notification to topics,the device must be subscribed to the topic.

here is how to subscribe a device to a topic

```
....
 FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
//subscribe to a notification
  _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("orders");
```

make sure user is subscribed to orders before adding order.